# Processing 3 - PVector Path offset // inward/outward polygon offsetting

Tags: coordinates, processing, polygon, offset

I've got a question that's driving me nuts! :) I've been working on it day and night now :) :)

**What is my goal?**
[image: I'm looking for a way for inward/outward polygon offsetting]

Say 2 outside. 2 inside. With Illustrator it is easy :)

**My approach so far**

1. Work clockwise. Get angle between P1 & P2
2. Use trigonometry to calculate the X & Y offset
3. Add the X & Y offset to P1 & P2. This is how I get the angle between P1 and P2:

```java
float getAngle = (atan((P1.y-P2.y)/(P1.x-p2.x))) * (180/PI) ;
```

2. 

```java
// ( COS(angle) = (adjacent side) / (hypotenuse) )   || 2 = 6 / 3
// ( COS(angle) * (hypotenuse) = (adjacent side)     || 2 * 3 = 6
            
// ( SIN(angle) = (opposite side) / (hypotenuse) )   || 2 = 6 / 3
// ( SIN(angle) * (hypotenuse) = (opposite side)     || 2 * 3 = 6
```

**My Problem**

- I know how to offset the path. But only on 1 side. Always +x and -Y. So this is the result. Almost like just moving the path entirely. Instead of offsetting all around.:

[image: So this is the result. Almost like just moving the path entirely. Instead of offsetting all around.]
It needs to stay outside the centre/original line.

**What would I like from you?**

- Is there a logic/formula to do this?
- Or is there a library that already has this??

I just cannot wrap my head around how I can keep the line offset outside the first/centre line.

Answer (score 0):

Could you get away with scaling the vertices ?

```
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  
  PVector[] originalPath = randomPath(7,100);
  
  PVector[] insetPath = scalePoints(originalPath,0.75);
  PVector[] outsetPath = scalePoints(originalPath,1.25);
  
  background(255);
  noFill();
  translate(width * .5, height * .5);
  stroke(0,192,0);
  drawPath(originalPath);
  stroke(192,0,0);
  drawPath(insetPath);
  stroke(0,0,192);
  drawPath(outsetPath);
  
  fill(0);
  text("original path",originalPath[0].x,originalPath[0].y);
  text("inset path",insetPath[1].x,insetPath[1].y);
  text("outset path",outsetPath[2].x,outsetPath[2].y);
  text("click\nto\nreset",0,0);
}

void drawPath(PVector[] pts){
  beginShape();
  for(PVector p : pts) vertex(p.x,p.y);
  endShape(CLOSE);
}

PVector[] scalePoints(PVector[] pts,float scale){
  int numPoints = pts.length;
  PVector[] result = new PVector[numPoints];
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numPoints; i++){
    result[i] = pts[i].get();
    result[i].mult(scale);
  }
  return result;
}

PVector[] randomPath(int numPoints,float r){
  PVector[] result = new PVector[numPoints];
  float ai = TWO_PI / numPoints;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numPoints; i++){
    float radius = random(r-r*.25,r+r*.25);
    result[i] = new PVector(cos(ai * i) * radius, sin(ai * i) * radius);
  }
  return result;
}

void mousePressed(){
  setup();
}
void draw(){}
```

[image: offset path demo (original, inset and offset path)]

Comment: cr*p, very sorry for the delay. I'm somehow not getting notifications.. 
Nevertheless thank you! I'm going to look into it. Looks promising!!

Comment: @Tim did you have luck with the snippet above ?